# rewrite rules for old url redirects to new url with query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm vainly trying to figure out why my redirections aren't working well. here is a sample of my htaccess file:

```
## activate rewriting engine
RewriteEngine on

## folders of languages
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /$2?tld=$1 [QSA,L]

## redirections
RewriteRule ^store/category1/category2/$ /store/category2/ [R=301,L]
```

As you can see, the website is multilingual (site.com/fr/, site.com/uk/, ...)

when i enter in the url site.com/fr/store/category1/category2/ it redirects me to site.com/store/category2/?tld=fr

do you have an idea why?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change order of your rules to keep `R` rules before rewrite ones:

```
## activate rewriting engine
RewriteEngine on

## redirections
RewriteRule ^store/category1/category2/$ /store/category2/ [R=301,L]

## folders of languages
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /$2?tld=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you Anubhava for your help and answer.
Indeed, i was "playing" with the htaccess file by trying different redirections and rules, and came up with your solution. BUT in some cases it still redirects with the ?tld=fr in some cases, the solution was to use a rule like this:
     RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/store/category1/category2/$ /$1/store/category2/ [R=301,L]
Do you think it's a good solution? :)

Comment: Yes that rule looks good. Just make sure you keep that new rule below last rule.

Comment: OK, thanks, by the way, is there a difference between [R=301,L] and [L,R=301] ??

Comment: Actually they are both same. Also if it worked out then you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: One last question please.
I have other rewriting rules for the catalogue for example, do all these rules have to be after RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /$2?tld=$1 [QSA,L] ??

Comment: You can keep those rules before very last rule.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it redirects you is because of this `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /$2?tld=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It is saying whatever is in the first capture group (the first set of parentheses), add to the new URL as $1 and the second capture group (the second set of parentheses) put at the beginning of the URL preceded by `/`

You have used the `L` flag on that rule, so it's the last rule in that rule set that Apache checks:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

Comment: Thank you Alex for your help :)
the solution is to change the order of the redirections... :)